# Не работают js скрипты на сайте WordPress'a

Tags: javascript, wordpress

[image: 1]

[image: 2]

В файл functions.php подключил все файлы:

```
function theme_name_scripts() {
        wp_enqueue_style( 'style', get_stylesheet_uri());
        wp_enqueue_style( 'bootstrap', get_template_directory_uri() . '/libs/Bootstrap-3.3.7/css/bootstrap.css');
        wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/jquery.min.js', '','null',true);
        wp_enqueue_script( 'bootstrapjs', get_template_directory_uri() . '/libs/Bootstrap-3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js', '','null',true);
        wp_enqueue_script( 'masonry', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/masonry.min.js', '','null',true);
        wp_enqueue_script( 'common', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/common.js', '','null',true);
    }

    add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'theme_name_scripts' );
```

Файлы подключаются в шапке, но не работают! Помогите пожалуйста!

Comment: То есть на страницу вставляются соответствующие теги `link` и `script`, но при этом стили подключаются а скрипты не работают? Есть ошибки в JavaScript консоли?

Comment: @tutankhamun, да все верно. Ошибок нету. Я предполагаю, что контэнтная часть грузится быстрее скриптов и по-этому они не работают.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. В коде нет экшена на `wp_enqueue_style`.
2. Нужно выкинуть из кода всё, касаемо стилей и jquery, а в самописную тему включить функции [wp_head](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_head) и [wp_footer](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_footer)

В любом случае при подобных проблема стоит проверять на темах из комплекта ВП.

Comment: Оно работает и без 1 пункта)